# React components not rendering within electron application when contextIsolation: true, but renders just fine when set to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, electron

I'm currently trying to learn the react framework and shifting my electron application from a standard Electron + HTML/CSS and incorporate react, but as I'm aware, you can't use a preload.js file without the contextIsolation being set to true, but for some reason whenever I set it to true, my react components doesn't render at all, the window opens just fine and there are no errors in the console, but the components simply just doesn't render/load. Does anyone have any idea to what I'm doing wrong? The version I'm using for each application is Electron (28.0.0), React (18.2.0), React-Dom (18.2.0). I've tried downgrading versions some or all packages and the problem of my react components rendering is strictly stemming from contextIsolation: true. **I've edited the question to also include my webpack.config.js**

./GUI/Auth/auth.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import LunarLogo from '../../Dependencies/lunar.png';
import './auth.css';

function Auth() {
  const [licenseKey, setLicenseKey] = useState('');
  const [authMessage, setAuthMessage] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = () => {
    if (licenseKey) {
        window.electron.validateLicense(licenseKey);
        
    } else {
        setAuthMessage('Input License Key');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="split-screen">
      <div class="drag-area"></div>
        <div className="left-pane">
            <div className="logo-container">
              <img src={LunarLogo} alt="Lunar Logo" className="logo" />
              <h1 className="app-name">Lunar Tools</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="welcome-text">
              <h2>Welcome to Lunar Tools</h2>
              <p>The last toolbox you'll ever need. Supporting all your botting needs!</p>
            </div>
            <div className="login-container">
              <span className="login-heading">Login</span>
              <p className="license-key-instruction">Enter your license key to continue</p>
              <input 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Enter Key" 
                className="license-input"
                value={licenseKey}
                onChange={(e) => setLicenseKey(e.target.value)}
              />
              <div className="button-container">
                <button className="login-btn" onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
                <button className="support-btn">Support</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            {authMessage && (
              <div className="authentication-status">
                <span style={{ color: '#B52D2D' }}>{authMessage}</span>
              </div>
            )}
        </div>
        <div className="right-pane">
          <img src={LunarLogo} alt="Clipart" className="right-clipart" />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Auth;
```

./GUI/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Auth from './Auth/auth';
import './index.css';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Auth />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

./GUI/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lunar</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6483512793.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const { autoUpdater, appUpdater } = require('electron-updater');
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize();

const discordRpc = require('./Functions/discordRpc');
const { startServer } = require('./Functions/server');
const { 
  decidePageToLoad, 
  validateLicenseHandler, 
  userDatabaseConnection, 
  applicationLaunched, 
  securityCheck 
} = require('./Functions/auth');

let mainWindow = null;
let serverAlreadyStarted = false;
const isDev = process.env.ELECTRON_ENV == 'dev';

autoUpdater.autoDownload = false;
autoUpdater.autoInstallOnAppQuit = true;

ipcMain.on('start-download', (event) => {
  autoUpdater.downloadUpdate();
});



autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
  console.log('Checking for updates...');
});

autoUpdater.on('update-available', (info) => {
  showUpdatePopup(info);
});
  
autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', (info) => {
  console.log('No updates available.', info);  
});

autoUpdater.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Error in auto-updater:', err);
});

autoUpdater.on('download-progress', (progressObj) => {
  let log_message = `Download speed: ${progressObj.bytesPerSecond}`;
  log_message = log_message + ` - Downloaded ${progressObj.percent}%`;
  log_message = log_message + ` (${progressObj.transferred}/${progressObj.total})`;
  
  win.webContents.send('download-progress', progressObj);
});

autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (info) => {
  autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
});


const renderWindow = async () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1400,
    height: 800,
    minWidth: 1400,
    minHeight: 800,
    frame: false,
    backgroundColor: '#0E0F16',
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      devTools: isDev,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    },
    icon: path.join(__dirname, './GUI/Dependencies/Lunar Logo.png'),
    resizable: true
  });
  require('@electron/remote/main').enable(mainWindow.webContents);

  ipcMain.on('validate-license', (event, inputLicenseKey) => {
    validateLicenseHandler(event, inputLicenseKey, mainWindow);
  });

  if (isDev) {
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/');

  } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile('./build/index.html');
  }

  mainWindow.setMenu(null);
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  /* mainWindow.webContents.on('devtools-opened', () => {
    mainWindow.webContents.closeDevTools();
  }); */

  ipcMain.on('validate-license', (event, inputLicenseKey) => {
    validateLicenseHandler(event, inputLicenseKey, win);
  });

  discordRpc();
  applicationLaunched();
  setInterval(() => {
    securityCheck()
  }, 10000);

  ipcMain.on('request-server-status', (event) => {
    if (!serverAlreadyStarted) {
      startServer((status) => {
        serverAlreadyStarted = true; 
        win.webContents.send('server-status-reply', status);
      });
    } else {
      win.webContents.send('server-status-reply', 'Connected');
    }
  });
};

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-gpu-blacklist');
app.disableHardwareAcceleration();
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  process.env.ELECTRON_DISABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS = 'true';
  renderWindow();
  require('./Functions/discordRpc');
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
});

module.exports.getMainWindow = () => mainWindow;
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = [
  {
    entry: './main.js',
    name: 'electron',
    target: 'electron-main',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".*",".js",".json"]
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/build',
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'app.js'
    },
    plugins: []
  },
  {
    entry: './GUI/index.js',
    name: 'react',
    target: 'electron-renderer',
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ['babel-loader']
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
          use: ['file-loader']
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".*",".js",".jsx",".json",".css",".svg"]
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/build',
      publicPath: './',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
      static: {
        directory: __dirname + '/build/',
      },
      compress: true
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'GUI/index.html'
      })
    ]
  }
];
```

preload.js

```
const remote = require('@electron/remote');
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer, shell } = require('electron');


contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
    close: () => remote.getCurrentWindow().close(),
    minimize: () => remote.getCurrentWindow().minimize(),
    getCurrentWindow: () => remote.getCurrentWindow(),
    receive: (channel, func) => {
        ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
    },
    validateLicense: (licenseKey) => {
        ipcRenderer.send('validate-license', licenseKey);
    },
    onAuthenticationFailed: (callback) => {
        ipcRenderer.on('authentication-failed', (event, message) => {
            callback(message);
        });
    },
    clearAuthenticationMessage: () => {
        ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('authentication-failed');
    }
});
```

Comment: The `nodeIntegration` should be `false` when you set `contextIsolation` as `true`.

Comment: I've tried this and its still not rendering the components

Comment: Is it in dev or prod mode? And what does your preload script do?

Comment: dev mode and my preload.js handles all the backend functionalities, such as communication between pop up windows and the main window when any data needs to be transferred between the two and any functions that need to be exposed globally

Comment: Probably worthwhile sharing the preload code, or at least ensure it does not interfere: what if it is an empty script?

Comment: i'll edit the question to include my preload.js as well

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out my issue, in any or all jsx files, I couldn't directly `import ipcRenderer` from the electron package and I also couldn't use this command `cross-env ELECTRON_ENV=dev electron ./build/app.js`, I had to directly run

```
electron .
```

with my main.js rather than my app.js that was bundled from the webpack.